# gRPC ASP.NET Core. Passing custom typed objects in .proto file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, protobuf-net

I'm trying to create gRPC service for my project.
I have a class:

```
public class ServiceObject
{
    public bool IsValuable { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public object Result { get; set; } 
    public string ResultCode { get; set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
}
```

Objects of which I want to receive from service.

I've read specification of gRPC/Protobuf from google, but haven't understood how to do this - I don't know how to pass `object` and custom-type class like `Exception`.

Other question.
Let's have `Location` class from GoogleApi C# library.

```
public class Location
{
    public Location();
    public Location(string address);
    public Location(double latitude, double longitude);
    [JsonProperty("lat")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lng")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public override string ToString();
}
```

How to automatically generate `.proto` file from classes I want to use for communication with service?

Thank you.

Comment: The usual gRPC development flow is the complete opposite: You specifiy in the `.proto` file your contracts. And then you use that to generate the services you need to implement. There is ongoing work for code-first gRPC but that isn’t ready yet. You could consider mapping the types as necessary to your internal types.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, what about custom-types and types like object or any c# specific types?

Comment: You will have to declare those within the `.proto` file, and then C# types will be generated for you. And then you can use those generated types and e.g. map them to your existing types.

Comment: @poke Could you explain me this deeper? Is it possible to add a small example of .proto file with code mapping `object` type and `Exception` type, please? Thank you!

Comment: Check out [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-3.0) on the topic. You should really stop focusing on your existing type and think about what data you actually want to transfer over the wire. You should design the `.proto` file without thinking about the implementation, or a particular language in mind. So having an `object` (which does not have any type information on its own), or an `Exception` (which is a very specific .NET thing) as part of your contract does not make that much sense.

Comment: If you want to work code-first rather than contract-first (.proto), you probably want to look at protobuf-net.Grpc; this atraches to the regular Google gRPC layer (and the new MS bits in .NET Core 3), and gives you what you want, I think

Comment: @poke heh, expect: protobuf-net.Grpc fills this exact hole :)

Comment: @MarcGravell I know, I’m following you on that topic ;) That’s what I was referring to above with _“there is ongoing work for code-first gRPC”_ ;)

Comment: Thank you guys!! Now reading project fiche on github, will try to use and implement the code I wish today. u2cool!!

Comment: @MarcGravell  I've read manual of your package. In the "Configuration Options" section you wrote that If I want to use own serializer, I should create new `ProtoBufMarshallerFactory` or implement a custom `MarshallerFactory`, rewritting `Serialize<T>` and `Deserialize<T>` methods. Could you explain a little how to do this? Is it possible to see a code example? I have complex types (like Exception or GoogleApi Location) and types consists of complex types. So, I want to use json serializer for this case (because default serializer gives me a serialization error). Thank you.

Comment: @Dmitriy I will try to add an example later today

Comment: @Marc Gravell, Oh, thank you, it would be cool! I'll wait for this!

Comment: @Dmitriy untested, but: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/e242aa5f3b14058fe1c7dbdcaf7fd124

Comment: @Marc Gravell, thank you. I have some questions. AddCodeFirstGrpc() has no input parameter - how to pass new BinderConfiguration object? Second question - MyJsonFactory contains private constructor, so I can't use `new` operator in `BinderConfiguration.Create`. So, should MyJsonFactory constructor be public (and other methods too)? Third - in the method `CanSerialize` I see `Foo` class for comparing. Is it correct that I could always return true if I want to damp protobuf serialization?  Thank you.

Comment: @Dmitriy if you want to drop protobuf serialization: don't include the `ProtoBufMarshallerFactory.Default`; the constructor: do whatever, it doesn't matter; re `BinderConfiguration` - in that case, it uses standard IOC, so: configure a `BinderConfiguration` via `services.AddSingleton` in `ConfigureServices`

Comment: @Marc Gravell,and what about AddCodeFirstGrpc? It has no parameters (no way to pass BinderConfiguration via AddCodeFirstGrpc)? Thank you.

Comment: @Dmitriy as I said: "re BinderConfiguration - in that case, it uses standard IOC, so: configure a BinderConfiguration via services.AddSingleton in ConfigureServices"

Comment: @Marc Gravell, ah, I see, sorry, my fault. It's a Friday, hard week night
)

Comment: @Marc Gravell, men, you'r f**n' genius!! Love you! It works amazing!!

Comment: @Dmitriy great, glad it is helping!

Comment: For passing error details, the best practice is to use this proto: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/proto/grpc/status/status.proto